# Passing values from database in "allowableValues"?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger version 2 with Java Spring. I have declared a property and it works fine and it generates a drop down list of value I assigned.

```
@ApiParam(value = "Pass any one Shuttle provider ID from the list", allowableValues = "1,2,3,4,10")
private Long hotelId;
```

Now, I need a way to populate this list which is passed in `allowableValues` from my database as it could be random list as well as huge data. How can I assign list of values dynamically from database in this `allowableValues`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You need to create constructor in SwaggerConfiguration class.
2. @Autowire service and withdraw data you need from database
3. assign this to `final` variable
4. assign this `final` variable to `allowableValues` in annotation
5. enjoy not efficient api

   ```
   private final String allowableValues;

   public SwaggerConfiguration() {
     List<YourEntitiy> list = someService.findAll();
     //code to get every value you need and add create comma separated String
     StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
     stringJoiner.add(list.get(0).getValue());

     this.allowableValues = stringJoiner.toString();
   }

   @ApiParam(allowableValues = allowableValues)
   ```

But I think it's bad idea getting all ids from database just to create allowable values. Just validate in api method if that id exist and/or Create new api to get ids from database, use pagination from Spring Data project, like [PageImpl<> javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.6.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I think I couldn't explain the question properly though this answer is very close to what I want to achieve. 

I want to fetch list of ariport names from my database and show this list in swagger as a "dropdown" list of values so that user may select any one airport from that list. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Comment: You asked how to populate this list and I showed you how to do this. It's impossible to do it dynamic, because spring building html view and just send it to web browser. Right now swagger not support any dynamic loadings.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but this wouldn't work: `allowableValues` must be filled with a compile time constant value (so something static final). You can't use something you would set in a constructor

Comment: It is impossible to assign an example value after compile time has been finished.

Answer (score 1):

This question is bit old, I too faced the same problem so thought of adding here which may help some one.

//For ApiModelProperty

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, allowableValues = "dynamicEnum(AddressType)")
@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
```

Created a component which implements ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin

```
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 1)
public class ApiModelPropertyPropertyBuilderCustom implements ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin {
    private final DescriptionResolver descriptions;

@Autowired
public ApiModelPropertyPropertyBuilderCustom(DescriptionResolver descriptions) {
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
}

public void apply(ModelPropertyContext context) {
    try {
        AllowableListValues allowableListValues = (AllowableListValues) FieldUtils.readField(context.getBuilder(),
                "allowableValues", true);
        if(allowableListValues!=null) {
            String allowableValuesString = allowableListValues.getValues().get(0);
            if (allowableValuesString.contains("dynamicEnum")) {
                String yourOwnStringOrDatabaseTable = allowableValuesString.substring(allowableValuesString.indexOf("(")+1, allowableValuesString.indexOf(")"));
                
                //Logic to Generate dynamic values and create a list out of it and then create AllowableListValues object

                context.getBuilder().allowableValues(allowableValues);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
    return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
}
}
```

Similary for ApiParam we can create component which will implement ParameterBuilderPlugin

```
@Override
public void apply(ParameterContext context) {
    @SuppressWarnings("Guava") final Optional<ApiParam> apiParam =
            context.resolvedMethodParameter().findAnnotation(ApiParam.class);

    if (apiParam.isPresent()) {
        final String allowableValuesString = apiParam.get().allowableValues();
        //Your logic here
        context.parameterBuilder().allowableValues(allowableValues);
        
    }
}
```